# Toggle Between Staggered and Linear Layouts (with one menu item)

Tags: java, android, view, toggle, layoutsubviews

Main Question
[ I want to be able to toggle between menu items Linear View and Staggered View without having two items shown as soon as one is clicked the view should change and the other menu item would show how can i accomplish this (similar to Google Keep) ]

i know that i need to set an event listener to the menu item once its clicked but not sure how to make one show and the other invisible when its not being used.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.linearView:
                LinearLayoutManager linearlayoutMang = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                linearlayoutMang.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearlayoutMang);
                listview.isEnabled();
                break;
            case R.id.staggerdView:
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutMang = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutMang);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: either change the icon or have 2 icons and hide/show the one whose mode you are not in

Comment: i have two icons but they are next to each other how would i make them be in the same spot just one visible and the other not when its displaying a layout

Comment: set the visibiliy to `GONE`

Comment: how will it know how to toggle between the two?

Comment: using the `onOptionsItemSelected` method